# How do I display/render image from mongoDB with reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I want to display images from MongoDB to react. I have done the backend work using django to get image and save it on my ../assets/ folder but when I try to fetch it by using  it is showing blank.
I need to change the port for image path as localhost:18000 from localhost:3000
by defaut react uses localhost:3000/img-path to get img

Comment: So set `src` to `'http://localhost:18000/assets/' + [image_name]`

Comment: @Mosh Feu <img class="card-img-top text-center" src={'http://localhost:18000' + data.course_details.course_image_url}  alt="Course image" style={{ width: "100%" }} />  but still using localhost:3000 when inspect code and check src

Comment: Add `http://` - `<img class="card-img-top text-center" src={'http://localhost:18000' + data.course_details.course_image_url} alt="Course image" style={{ width: "100%" }} />`

Comment: @Mosh Feu can you explain clearly. I am not getting your point

Comment: I can try :) In the comment above, the url you set start with `localhost:18000` probably cause problems. Instead it should start with `http://` then `localhost:18000`. Is it more clear?

Comment: @Mosh Feu ,yes now its clear. and I was already using http:  but I was doing mistake somewhere else. Thank you so much .now it is solved

Comment: Glad to hear :) Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setState()` for store images and use `fetch()` to call an API

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Main extends Component {
    state = {
        data : []
    }
    componentDidMount(){

        fetch('http://localhost:18000/').then(res => res.json())
        .then(data=> this.setState({data}))

    }
    render() {

        console.log(this.state.data)

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Main</h1>
                {this.state.data ? this.state.data.map(img => 
                (<div key={img._id}>{img ? <img src={require(`${img.img.path}`)} 
                alt={img.img.name}/>:<span>deleted</span>}</div>)): 
                <h3>loading</h3>}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: here you did not discuss to change port for image